# What is causing this error - "Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I removed the old version of grunt first, then I installed the new grunt version, and then I got this error:

> D:\www\grunt-test\grunt grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface.
>   (v0.1.4)
>
> Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
>
> If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or
>   grunt hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more
>   information about installing and configuring grunt, please see the
>   Getting Started guide: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Is this because there is not a reference to grunt in my system path? Or something else? I tried to re-install it a few times already.

Comment: Did you install globally? `npm install grunt -g`

Comment: do you have a `Gruntfile.js` at the root of your project?

Comment: @elclanrs Yes,I do this.

Comment: @Simon Boudrias Gruntfile.js is in the grunt-test directory.

Comment: This question is closed, but in case it helps anyone else:  in my case I had simply forgotten to add `grunt` itself to my `package.json`. The new version of `grunt-cli` doesn't actually install grunt, it relies on the package being there.

Comment: @Gromix can you share the line you added to the package.json?

Comment: @Garreh It's been a while, but try `npm install grunt --save-dev` from the terminal. This should add the latest version to your `package.json`.

Comment: @Gromix My issue was unsuccessfully getting grunt from a local repo. Using npm's repo in my config allowed me to install grunt correctly.

Comment: Oops - had this with a newly checked out project. Just needed to do `npm install`!

Comment: nmp install  - Installs the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.

Comment: I had the same problem, but the problem was that npm install wasn't working, found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443526/npm-installs-all-modules-in-usr-local-lib-node-modules

Comment: Hi Anyone please replay on below query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917714/grunt-how-to-keep-node-modules-folder-globally-and-use-it-in-all-project-for

Comment: if you are a exists project. maybe should execute   npm install.

Comment: step 2.  http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#working-with-an-existing-grunt-project

Answer (score 305, accepted):

I think you don't have a `grunt.js` file in your project directory.  Use `grunt:init`, which gives you options such as `jQuery, node,commonjs`.  Select what you want, then proceed.  This really works. For more information you can visit [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/meeting-grunt-the-build-tool-for-javascript/).

Do this:

```
 1. npm install -g grunt
 2. grunt:init  ( you will get following options ):
      jquery: A jQuery plugin
      node: A Node module
      commonjs: A CommonJS module
      gruntplugin: A Grunt plugin
      gruntfile: A Gruntfile (grunt.js)
 3 .grunt init:jquery (if you want to create a jQuery related project.).
```

It should work.

Solution for v1.4:

```
1. npm install -g grunt-cli
2. npm init
   fill all details and it will create a package.json file.
3. npm install grunt (for grunt dependencies.)
```

**Edit : Updated solution for new versions:**

```
 npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Comment: This version must be the old one(v0.3).today I'm unintsalled it,and install the new grunt(v0.4) called Grunt-CLI.something has changed..

Comment: I added solution for new version also.

Comment: Currently, `npm install grunt` installs grunt 0.3.x.  You'll need to do `npm install grunt@0.4' go locally install the version of grunt needed for grunt-cli

Comment: I wish the Grunt install steps would address the @0.4.  Was really wringing my hands trying to figure this out until I found your comment.

Comment: `npm install grunt --save-dev` did it for me

Comment: `grunt-cli` should be installed globally, but it expects you to have a local install of `grunt.js` in your project. This allows each project to use a different version of grunt. I typically use npm with a package.json file to install grunt.js all any other grunt conribs etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "grunt grunt:init"?

Comment: npm install grunt --save-dev did the job for me.

Answer (score 192):

### Install Grunt in node_modules rather than globally

`Unable to find local Grunt` likely means that you have installed Grunt globally.

The Grunt CLI insists that you install grunt in your local node_modules directory, so Grunt is local to your project.

This will fail:

```
npm install -g grunt
```

Do this instead:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Comment: This solved my issue. Not sure how it isn't accepted. Good stuff.

Answer (score 86):

Do

```
npm install
```

to install Grunt locally in `./node_modules` (and everything else specified in the `package.json` file)

Comment: I did that cause like a fool I forgot running this command after pulling the new fresh project's repo to mac..... :/

Comment: How come grunt needs to be installed locally since the command line tool can always be located globally?

Comment: @MikeM sometimes you have `node_modules/.bin` in your `PATH`. Also, local and global can be different versions.

Comment: In my case it was NetBeans' fault. Sometimes it crashes my projects when I do `git stash` in external tool, here it removed some modules from `node_modules` and everything stopped working (and was working fine before). After `npm install` it works well again.

Answer (score 27):

If you already have a file `package.json` in the project and it contains `grunt` in dependency,

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.0",
```

Then you can run `npm install` to resolve the issue

Answer (score 7):

I made the mistake to install some packages using sudo and other without privileges , this fixed my problem.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $HOME/.npm
```

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

It says you don't have a local `grunt` so try:

`npm install grunt`

(without the `-g` it's a local `grunt`)

Though not directly related, make sure you have `Gruntfile.js` in your current folder.

Answer (score 4):

Could be a few problems here depending on what version of grunt is being used. Newer versions of grunt actually specify that you have a file named `Gruntfile.js` (instead of the old `grunt.js`).

You should have the `grunt-cli` tool be installed globally (this is done via `npm install -g grunt-cli`). This allows you to actually run `grunt` commands from the command line.

Secondly make sure you've installed grunt locally for your project. If you see your `package.json` doesn't have something like `"grunt": "0.4.5"` in it then you should do `npm install grunt --save` in your project directory.

Answer (score 3):

I had to execute the following commands on ubuntu to solve this problem (I know grunt for 1 hour) :

```
sudo npm install -g grunt
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli

cd /usr/local/bin
# current symlink points to ../lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt*
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/grunt
sudo ln -s ../lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt* grunt
```

It is dirty but it is the only one solution I found... :(

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run this command:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me because i had grunt installed globally (recommended in several of these answers, oddly) and that was messing everything up.  Here's what did work:

```
npm uninstall -g grunt
npm install
```

Only now was a local grunt installed, and useable, for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just `npm install` to install `node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

Being new to grunt and setting it up, I am running (perhaps foolishly) my grunt project/folder from a Google Drive so I can access the same code/builds from either my laptop or workstation.

There is a fair bit of synchronisation of the nodes_modules folders back to Google Drive and there seemed to be a conflict at some point, and the /nodes_modules/grunt folder was renamed to /nodes_modules/grunt (1)

Renaming it back by removing the (1) seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: Why don't you use GIT?

Comment: I wasnt wanting to track/versions changes and was trying not to maintain two separate grunt installs, but the above scenario was fairly problematic so I have moved around to github anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Vagrant.

I have used sudo to run the command to install.

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

It worked for me.