# "Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt." on Windows 7

Tags: gruntjs

I cannot get grunt to work at all on Windows 7. Following the instructions on the Grunt website (http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) I've run:

```
npm uninstall -g grunt-cli
npm uninstall grunt
npm uninstall -g grunt-init

git clone git@github.com:gruntjs/grunt-init-jquery.git c:/Users/me/.grunt-init/jquery

npm install -g grunt-cli
grunt-init jquery
npm install .
```

After that, running "grunt" produces the following output:

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.9)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

The output of npm list grunt is:

```
npm WARN package.json consolidate@0.9.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json jquery-plugin@0.0.0-ignored No repository field.
npm WARN package.json passport-local-examples-login@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json receiptly@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json cookie-signature@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json fresh@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json range-parser@0.0.4 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json send@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json pause@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json policyfile@0.0.4 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
npm WARN package.json eyes@0.1.8 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json bytes@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json uid2@0.0.2 No repository field.
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm
└─┬ grunt-init@0.2.1
  └── grunt@0.4.1
```

Running "npm install grunt" in the current directory gives the same error when running grunt.

Any thoughts? My understanding is that grunt-cli is meant to look for a local grunt install, but I can't work out why it can't find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925916/fatal-error-unable-to-find-local-grunt/13927654#13927654 , this may help.

Comment: You need a local instance of grunt. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27115342/687677

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know its been 2 years since this question was asked. However if someone wants in future:

I got the exact same issue. And I got this fixed by installing grunt **locally**. As per grunt [site](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started),

> Note that installing grunt-cli does not install the Grunt task runner!
>   The job of the Grunt CLI is simple: run the version of Grunt which has
>   been installed next to a Gruntfile. This allows multiple versions of
>   Grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.

So I just got it working by installing Grunt locally.

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

--save : adds it to your package.json.

-dev: adds it as a dev dependency.

Answer (score 3):

There must be a Gruntfile.js located in the directory you run the command from. Also double check that 'npm install grunt' actually gave you a node_modules directory with a sub directory called grunt.

Answer (score 1):

You should install `grunt` in GUI mode.

Open `node.js` cmd prompt then open the root folder and run the below commands

1. `npm install` ( once it done you can able to see `node_modules` folder in the root folder)
2. `npm install –g  grunt-cli` (change the version from (`"version": "minified"` to `Current release("version":"1.11")`; you should replace with minified once you run build)
3. `grunt build:full`

Note: Version has to change when running `grunt` very first time.

Answer (score 0):

if the above answer do not works then you can try by using this

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install
```