# Unable to find local grunt when using grung ngtemplates

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs

Following the instruction for setting up grunt angular templates: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates

I install the grunt-angular-template by doing:

```
npm install grunt-angular-templates --save-dev
```

It installs.

My package.json is just a very simple:

```
{
  "name": "grunt_example2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-angular-templates": "~0.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause"
}
```

And I create a Gruntfile.js as

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadTasks('grunt-angular-templates');
}
```

when I do:

```
grunt ngtemplates
```

I get: 
    Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

```
If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

But that gives me nothing on how to resolve this.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925916/fatal-error-unable-to-find-local-grunt/13927654#13927654   , this may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install grunt into your project. See here: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-grunt-and-gruntplugins

`npm install grunt --save-dev`

Comment: but why does it have to be local? I want to do sudo npm install -g grunt

Comment: @FutuToad You need 'grunt-cli' installed globally (which will create the 'grunt' application), then you need to install 'grunt' locally to run the tasks. Please, read the documentation.

Comment: gotcha! but its pretty weird needing to istall everything locally