# `Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.`: why asking for local grunt, if I have a global?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm a noob in Node.js and trying to use `grunt-contrib-concat` to build my javascript library from multiple source files.

I've created a virtual environment, activated it, globally installed `grunt` and `grunt-cli`, written `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` files for my project. To summarize:

```
$ nodenv NODEENV
$ source NODENV/bin/activate
(NODEENV)$ npm install -g grunt-cli
...
(NODEENV)$ npm install -g grunt
...
(NODEENV)$ cd myproject
(NODEENV)$ ls myproject
Gruntfile.js package.json src test README.md
(NODEENV)$ grunt test
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

What I don't understand is why `grunt-cli` is telling me that it wants a local per-project version of `grunt` if I've already got a globally installed one?

Could you also suggest a way to fix the error?

Comment: Did you try `npm install` from your project directory? I'm a Grunt noob, but I'm fairly certain it has to reside in your project's `node_modules` directory to assert your project is using the correct version of grunt.

Comment: @Mike: thanks. Indeed, it worked. I wonder, if installing Grub globally is pointless?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27115342/687677

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's due to [npm's foldering](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/folders.html):

> - Install it **locally** if you're going to `require()` it.
> - Install it **globally** if you're going to run it on the command line.

The Gruntfile itself depends on `require('grunt')` being available, requiring a local install.

```
$ npm install grunt
```

And, having `grunt(1)` as an available command makes using the tool easier, requiring a global install.

```
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
```

To have both, though, it has to be installed in both folders.

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install` from your project directory. For each project, Grunt needs to reside in the `npm_modules` directory of your project in order for the project to assert that it is using the correct version of grunt (which may differ from your global version).

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way it works. You always need to:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install grunt
```

Answer (score 0):

If these commands does not work with/without sudo.

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install grunt
```

or you are getting error like this

[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

Then follow these steps.

1. Run `npm config list`
   then check for registry key value.
   it can be like:

   `registry = "https://npm.some.domain.other.than.global.com/"`
2. if you found your case as step 1 then run command

   `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/`

Done!!

Now you can run
`npm install` if your `package.json` contains `grunt` library name,

otherwise

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install grunt
```

It will work now.