# Grunt command - unable to find local grunt

Tags: gruntjs, npm

I copied an existing Grunt project from git repo and when i run - grunt serve-dev command it tells me the following:

```
 Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

 If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
 hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
 installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

 http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

But if i - grunt -version it says:grunt-cli v0.1.13.

What might be the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925916/fatal-error-unable-to-find-local-grunt)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to run `npm install` after cloning the repo. Usually the `node_modules`, such as `grunt` aren't included the repo itself by default, but you must install them yourself.