# Building angular fork fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, npm

I created a fork of [angularJs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) and I'm trying to build it. Unfortunately this fails when I run `grunt package`

`npm -v` --> `3.5.2`

`bower --version` --> `1.7.2`

I followed the [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute) to build angular:

```
$ npm install
$ bower install
$ grunt package
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

Did I forget something?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925916/fatal-error-unable-to-find-local-grunt?rq=1

Comment: I have read that issue and it is not the same here. I have a GruntFile and package.json (since it's a fork from angularjs ...)

Comment: try `sudo npm i -g grunt-cli` you may or may not need the sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it has something todo with npm 3.5.4 because I was getting a cache error with this version.

But after downgrading to npm 2.x everything worked perfectly.