# layout is rendered incorrectly on Jekyll blog on Github

Tags: jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I fork a Jekyll theme from this repository https://github.com/madforjekyll/madforjekyll.github.io the blog works well in its original repo. But in my repo, I didn't change anything, the layout rendered incorrectly, as shown in the picture. Tried reading other blogs to find a solution, but still no clue. Please help. Thanks
[blog picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acQq5.png)

Comment: Do you have an url we can see your blog?

Comment: Sorry, not allow newbies to post more than 2 URLs in a post. 
here is my repo https://github.com/KimTrijnh/KimTrijnh.github.io

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by changing https:// to http:// after finding out the some js and ajax not allowed to load because of that.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at recent forks of that repository, and I'm guessing this one is yours? https://github.com/KimTrijnh/KimTrijnh.github.io

It's helpful for that information to be included in future posts as it allows others to see the code in question.

I cloned the repo and tried getting it up and running locally and it wouldn't work without some modifications. I believe that `package.json` is missing some dependencies.

After I modified `package.json` to include these new dependencies, the site worked properly.

`package.json`: (Revision)

`"dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-banner": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "magnific-popup": "^1.0.0"
  },`

I determined this because of warning outputs when running the site locally using Grunt. References: [Grunt Getting Started](https://gruntjs.com/getting-started), [Error I ran Into Doing This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925916/fatal-error-unable-to-find-local-grunt)

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work after modifying. I then investigated the page, it turned out that because the https security requirement, some Js and ajax are not allowed to load. I used http://... then it works fine.