# "Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt." when running "grunt" command

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I uninstalled grunt with following command.

```
npm uninstall -g grunt
```

Then I again installed grunt with following command.

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Visit following link: 
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-html

I want to use the above grunt plugin

But when I run the grunt command it gives me following error:

```
D:\nodeJS\node_modules\grunt-html>grunt
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.6)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with jQuery. You have to install grunt in your project directory, just as explained in the documentation: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-grunt-and-gruntplugins. The error message also says: *"[...] or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project."*.

Comment: I successfully installed grunt in my project directory. Now how can i used that plugin

Comment: You install the plugin and follow the instructions on its project's page, the page you linked to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925916/fatal-error-unable-to-find-local-grunt/13927654#13927654  , this may help

Answer (score 177, accepted):

All is explained quite nicely on [gruntjs.com](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started).

> Note that installing grunt-cli does not install the grunt task runner!
>   The job of the grunt CLI is simple: run the version of grunt which has
>   been installed next to a Gruntfile. This allows multiple versions of
>   grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.

So in your project folder, you will need to install (preferably) the **latest grunt version**:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Option `--save-dev` will add `grunt` as a **dev-dependency** to your **package.json**. This makes it easy to reinstall dependencies.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but probably it was done because your second line is unnecessary and pedantic.

Comment: @LeeWhitney I've removed the line, I just meant that the error message mentions the link to the getting started guide, which should be the first place to look for answers.

Answer (score 20):

You have to install grunt in your project folder

1. create your package.json

   ```
   $ npm init
   ```
2. install grunt for this project, this will be installed under `node_modules/`. --save-dev will add this module to devDependency in your package.json

   ```
   $ npm install grunt --save-dev
   ```
3. then create gruntfile.js and run

   ```
   $ grunt
   ```

Comment: Also, make sure that the node-modules folder is being created. Mine wasn't because npm had `global=true` configuration. I've found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13449393/1046584

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to add grunt to your `package.json` file. See [this link](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Getting-started#packagejson).

Comment: @mpang the link is dead

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue on my Windows grunt because I installed the 32 bit version of Node on a 64 bit Windows OS. When I installed the 64bit version specifically, it started working.

Comment: +1 from me... I wonder why this got voted down. This seems like a perfectly plausible reason for grunt failing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today on windows 32 bit,with node 0.10.25, and grunt 0.4.5.

I followed [dongho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20277420/3556874), with just few extra steps.
here are the steps I used to solve the error:

1) create your package.json

```
$ npm init
```

2) install grunt for this project, this will be installed under node_modules/. --save-dev will add this module to devDependency in your package.json

```
$ npm install grunt --save-dev
```

3) then create `gruntfile.js` , with a sample code like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: ['jshint']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

};
```

here, `src/**/*.js` and `test/**/*.js` should be the paths to actual JS files you are using in your project

4) run `npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev`

5) run `npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev`

6) run `$ grunt`

**Note:** when you require common package like concat, uglify etc, you need to add those modules via `npm install`, just the way we installed jshint and watch in step 4 & 5

Answer (score 1):

if you are a exists project, maybe should execute npm install.

[guntjs getting started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#working-with-an-existing-grunt-project) step 2.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me. I mistakenly installed grunt using:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt --save-dev
```

and then ran the following command in the project folder:

```
npm install
```

This resulted in the error seen by the author of the question.
I then uninstalled grunt using:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g grunt
```

Deleted the node_modules folder. And reinstalled grunt using:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

and running the following in the project folder:

```
npm install
```

For some odd reason when you global install grunt using -g and then uninstall it, the node_modules folder holds on to something that prevents grunt from being installed locally to the project folder.