# grunt Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt in Yeoman

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I installed yeoman and started the examples which are provided in the official documentation.
I went through the  suggested operations

```
    yo webapp 
    bower install underscore  
    grunt
```

After running grunt I have the message

```
    grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.9)

    Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

    If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
    hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
    installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

    http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

Note that grunt have been installed with

```
    npm install -g grunt-cli
```

and

```
    npm install -g grunt
```

yo has generated the Gruntfile.js in the project root, where I am running the command.
The package.json has been generated as well:

```
    "name": "testyo",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "~0.4.1",
      "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
      "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.3",
      "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.6.5",
      "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
      "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.2.0",
      "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.4.1",
      "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
      "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.2.0",
      "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.0",
      "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
      "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.1.3",
      "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.0",
      "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
      "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.1.20130516",
      "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.10",
      "grunt-mocha": "~0.3.0",
      "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
      "grunt-svgmin": "~0.1.0",
      "grunt-concurrent": "~0.1.0",
      "matchdep": "~0.1.1",
      "connect-livereload": "~0.2.0"
    },
    "engines": {
      "node": ">=0.8.0"
    }
```

Additionally. From the root directory

```
    grunt --version
    grunt-cli v0.1.9
```

This confirm that grunt is available to be run in every directory.
Any idea?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

After some quick research I realized, from the [grunt documentation](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started), that grunt has to be installed in the project. I did that by running:

```
    sudo npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Now grunt works.

I also needed to run:

```
    npm install
```

so that all the dependencies are loaded.

This solved my problem. To be honest I thought yeoman would have taken care of the last two steps automatically.

In case you have comments or think there is a better solution, please leave a comment.

Comment: After scaffolding, Yeoman automatically calls `npm install` as well as `bower install`. Like everything in the software world, sometimes bugs come up. For some reason, during your scaffolding, the process must have escaped too soon from an error, preventing `npm install` to have been run by default.

Comment: thanx for your reply. I already checked all the source code :-).  Left  my post in case can be useful for some other person new to yeoman.

Comment: weird, I just had to redo npm install when I changed git branches from my non angular branch back to my angular one

Comment: Thanks for this. Was going insane trying to find out why grunt wasn't working. Turns out the initial npm install for grunt and yeoman (triedboth) didn't run an npm install. Worked! Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Comment: Had a similar problem on Ubuntu Linux 12.10. This solved my issue too. Thx! +1 to both

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Please consider checking out [npm's docs on using sudo with npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Answer (score 13):

```
npm cache clean
sudo npm install grunt --save-dev
```

really did the trick for me

Comment: I am on OS X - and this fixed mine as well.  Thank you for sharing, without your tip I would have been searching longer.  For anyone reading and is new to Grunt - also install Bower.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem.

After running `npm install`, make sure a *node_modules* folder is created in the root of your project. This is the folder where "local grunt" will be placed. If the folder is not there, check your npm cofiguration `npm config ls` and make sure you have `global=false`.

I've found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13449393/1046584